# How to calculate g-force using x, y, z values from the accelerometer in Android 1.6

Tags: android

I can get the three x, y, and z values from the accelerometer in Android. How can I use these to calculate the g-force?

Comment: @Yman .. please be clear with your comment.. what you want to say from your comment?

Answer (score 18):

If the accelerometer measures acceleration in meters per second squared (the SI unit), you can convert each acceleration into a [g-force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force) measurement by dividing by `9.81`.

If you want the g-force as an directionless measurement, you just need to apply [the pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to the different components of the acceleration:

```
double g = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
```

Comment: Should not be `double g = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z) / 9.8;`?

Answer (score 0):

Just select `TYPE_GRAVITY` instead of `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` as sensor type:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-grav